# Remove Fragment From TabLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I want to delete a fragment and it's view from a tablayout when a checkbox is checked from a recyclerview. I have skipped the initializing codes and will share only the adapter codes (as that's where the work is) like below:

ViewpagerAdapter code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private static final String TAG = ViewPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> titlesList = new ArrayList<>();

private Context context;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context ctx, ViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = ctx;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
    this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragTab(Fragment fragment, String name){
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    titlesList.add(name);
}

public void addFragLastPosition(Fragment fragment, String name){
    fragmentList.add(fragmentList.size(), fragment);
    titlesList.add(name);
}

public void removeFrag(int position){
    removeTab(position);
    Fragment fragment = fragmentList.get(position);
    fragmentList.remove(fragment);
    titlesList.remove(position);
    destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void destroyFragmentView(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
    FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) obj).getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.remove((Fragment) obj).commit();
}

private void removeTab(int position) {
    if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 2){
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titlesList.get(position);
}

}
```

and recyclerview adapter with checkbox to delete and add fragment:

```
public class PrefsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrefsCustomizeViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = PrefsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context context;
private List<Customize> itemsList;

private long id_nature, id_space;
private Customize cust;

private String nature, space;

private ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public PrefsAdapter(Context context, List<Customize> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager());
}

@Override
public PrefsCustomizeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.prefs_customize_items_layout, parent, false);
    return new PrefsCustomizeViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PrefsCustomizeViewHolder viewholder, final int position) {
    final Customize customize = itemsList.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(customize.getIcon())
            .fit()
            .into(viewholder.prefsSelImg);

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            cust = new Select()
                    .from(Customize.class)
                    .where("tabName = ? ", Constants.NATURE)
                    .executeSingle();
            if (cust != null) {
                nature = cust.tabName;
                Log.d(TAG, "Nature Tab From DB:\t" + nature);
                id_nature = cust.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "Nature Tab Id from DB:\t" + id_nature);
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            cust = new Select()
                    .from(Customize.class)
                    .where("tabName = ? ", Constants.SPACE)
                    .executeSingle();
            if (cust != null) {
                space = cust.tabName;
                Log.d(TAG, "Space Tab From DB:\t" + space);
                id_space = cust.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "Space Tab Id from DB:\t" + id_space);
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
    }

    viewholder.prefsSelImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    if (viewholder.prefsCheckBox.isChecked()){
                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                        //Customize.delete(Customize.class, id_nature);
                        pagerAdapter.removeFrag(1); // not working
                    } else {
                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                        customize.setTabId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        customize.setTabName(Constants.NATURE);
                        customize.save();

                        pagerAdapter.addFragTab(new NatureFrag(), Constants.NATURE); // not working too
                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (viewholder.prefsCheckBox.isChecked()){
                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(false);

                        Customize.delete(Customize.class, id_space);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted Space id:\t" + id_space); // prints right log detail
                        pagerAdapter.removeTab(new SpaceFragment(), Constants.SPACE);

                    } else {
                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setChecked(true);

                        customize.setTabId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        customize.setTabName(Constants.NATURE);
                        customize.save();

                        pagerAdapter.addTab(new SpaceFragment(), Constants.SPACE);

                        viewholder.prefsCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}

}
```

The method to delete the tab doesn't work. Can anyone help out with this implementation or another way? Thanks.